# Running handler thread before UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am trying to get json data from dump (which is a map). So Idea is when a activity is launched background thread read Json data and dump. Now UI thread runs and ArrayList should be updated from dump data.

My Code is

```
Public class myclass extends ListActivity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyHandlerMethod();
ArrayList deals = new ArrayList(SessionStore.getFromDump("someData"));
}

MyHandlerMethod(){

//A handler thread
//Json parsing and adding data to dump runs here
 }

}
```

//Sessionstore class have getFromDump() method which have map inside to store data.

// When MyHandlerMethod is run this map should be updated.

But I every time UI thread is running before MyHandlerMethod() so SessionStore.getFromDump("someData") remain null.

How can I assure to run Handler thread prior to UI thread.

Its a list activity. What actually I want is arraylist should be get updated from dump and I use that array list for list activity.

Comment: Well the thread is called from the main thread (main UI), so you can't run it before that, you can however wait for the background thread to finish and then display, that way you will not get any null on `SessionStore.getFromDump("someData")`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an **AsyncTask** for that, and update your UI with the onProgressUpdate / publishProgress and onPostExecute   methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here is an example of how it could work:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]); // here you can for example update your progress bar, your textviews, whatever UI...
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I hope this answer is clear enough for you. Otherwise do not hesitate to ask for detailed information.

Comment: How asyncTask will update dump data before ArrayList in UI thread is executed. It is same as handler.

Comment: Simply initialize your ArrayList when the Activity is created, and then add the items to the ArrayList in the onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute Method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AsyncTask to get Data data and then update the UI thread. 
[Here the reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

You basically cannot run a HandlerThread before the UI thread. But you can wait for the background task to load the images while showing a ProgressDialog, for example.
I recommend you using an AsyncTask.

This is a good tutorial about background processes, including AsyncTask.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't use an `AsyncTask`, maybe you want to specify `Thread` priority or whatever.

You can start a `HandlerThread` then call `getLooper()` to get the its `Looper` which you can then pass to a `Handler` so that it may receive and handle messages on that thread.

But using an `AsyncTask` is the simple solution.